# Updating nested objects in reducers

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm using react, typescript, redux to create a simple app that manage my ingredients but somehow I couldn't manage it with my code. I have the following:

my types declared in this file types.ts:

```
export interface Mytype {
  a: number;
  b: number;
  c: number;
  d: number;
}

export interface Mytype2 {
  Mytypes: Mytype[];
}

export const ADD = "INGREDIENT";
export const DELETE = "INGREDIENT";

interface AddA {
  type: typeof ADD;
  aName: Mytype;
}

interface DeleteA {
  type: typeof DELETE;
  aName: Mytype;
}

export type OrderActionTypes = AddA | DeleteA;
```

Comment: I see in initialState has Ingredient but you are using state.Ingredients..

Comment: can you elaborate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn this

```
[...action.ingredientName]: state.ingredients[action.ingredientName] + 1
```

into this

```
[action.ingredientName]: state.ingredients[action.ingredientName] + 1
```

and also remove the array inside your `DELETE` cases, since the initial state is an object not an array.

```
case DELETE_INGREDIENT:
      return {
          ...state, 
        [action.ingredientName]: state[action.ingredientName] - 1
          
      };
```

and change your types here

```
import {
  Ingredient,
  ADD_INGREDIENT,
  DELETE_INGREDIENT,
  OrderActionTypes,
} from "./types";

export function addIngredient(newIngredient: keyof Ingredient): OrderActionTypes {
  return {
    type: ADD_INGREDIENT,
    ingredientName: newIngredient,
  };
}

export function deleteIngredient(Ingredient: keyof Ingredient): OrderActionTypes {
  return {
    type: DELETE_INGREDIENT,
    ingredientName: Ingredient,
  };
}
```

and in your types

```
export interface Ingredient {
  cheese: number;
  bacon: number;
  mushrooms: number;
  ananas: number;
}

export const ADD_INGREDIENT = "ADD_INGREDIENT";
export const DELETE_INGREDIENT = "DELETE_INGREDIENT";

interface AddIngredientAction {
  type: typeof ADD_INGREDIENT;
  ingredientName: keyof Ingredient;
}

interface DeleteIngredientAction {
  type: typeof DELETE_INGREDIENT;
  ingredientName: keyof Ingredient;
}

export type OrderActionTypes = AddIngredientAction | DeleteIngredientAction;
```

Comment: thanks for the help but tried it already and but didnt work

Comment: Post your components too. Does the reducer get the updated value they want?

Comment: my components are super simple and were using contextAPI before but now I migrate to redux and didn't get the data yet using the actual code

Comment: Post your components, mate. Your reducer and action seems to be okay.

Comment: Also post the example of your dummy date , your data type doesn't match the return data type from your reducer.

Comment: I have added what I got when I applied your fix and I have edited the post to show the new error

Comment: I'm trying to return an object and I have specified that in the interface in types.ts file but still getting an error as you see

Comment: You should be spreading only `state` not `state.Ingrediants`. There is no `Ingrediants` property inside your state. Check the updated answer above.

Comment: did that but in [action.ingredient] I get this now: Property 'ingredient' does not exist on type 'AddIngredientAction'

Comment: Also use `[action.ingredientName]` instead of `[action.ingredient]`. Is this the first time you're using Typescript?

Comment: my first using typescript with redux yes

Comment: I will upload the new screenshot after following your updates

Comment: You need to learn how to use types in Typescript. Read the docs, watch the tutorial, and post the whole code. Your types are all messed up. Your code is okay now. Fix your types.

Comment: I appreciate your comment and help, thanks for that, maybe I will try to learn next time ;)

Comment: check the new updated code... and learn things before using it.

Comment: Hey again! do you have an idea where would be the case when I have an object which is going be like this: interface Ingredient {
  name: string;
  ingredients: {
    cheese: number;
    bacon: number;
    mushrooms: number;
    ananas: number;
  };
}.
where I have an action will add only a matched ingredient, and another will delete a matched ingredient and another action will add a whole new ingredients with the name? do you have an idea maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this:

```
const initialState= {
 Ingredient: {
      cheese: 0,
      bacon: 0,
      mushrooms: 0,
      bananas: 0,
}
}
```

as your initialState has Ingredient, so use state.Ingredient:

```
case DELETE_INGREDIENT:
      return {
       Ingredients: [
          ...state.Ingredient, 
        [action.ingredient]: state.Ingredient[action.ingredient] -1
          
        ],
      };
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but the response of Prateek worked now :)

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Comment: Hey again! do you have an idea where would be the case when I have an object which is going be like this: interface Ingredient {
  name: string;
  ingredients: {
    cheese: number;
    bacon: number;
    mushrooms: number;
    ananas: number;
  };
}.
where I have an action will add only a matched ingredient, and another will delete a matched ingredient and another action will add a whole new ingredients with the name? do you have an idea maybe?